# How to get list in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

What I have to do if I want that kind of output? I cant get that Hours: list out right. My output look Hours: 6 6 6 6 6.

```
How many days:
4
1. day h:7
2. day h:8
3. day h:9
4. day h:5.4
Total hours: 29.4
Average working day: 7.35
Hours: 7 8 9 5.4
```

My code look like that

```
cout << "How many days:\n";
cin >> days;

for(ind=0; ind<days; ind++) {
  cout << ind+1 << ". day h: ";
  cin >> hours;
  sum += hours;
}

cout << "Total hours: " << sum << endl;
average = sum/days;

cout << "Average working day: " << average << endl;
cout << "Hours: ";
for(ind=0; ind<days; ind++) {
  cout << hours << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: You somewhat answered your own question with your question title. You need a container (a list is adequate, as is a vector, deque, etc) to retain your input values for regurgitation during output. Right now you're repeatedly spewing the *last* hour value read.

Comment: _"Hours: 6 6 6 6 6."_ What should this output actually mean? Would you mind to elaborate please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I believe "Hour: 6 6 6" means "the apocalypse is upon us!"

Comment: @JerryCoffin That doesn't explain the postfixed two 6 there though :-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The apocalypse tends to distract from such minor concerns.

Comment: @JerryCoffin LOL! You're cool man, sure big things wont be attracted from minor concerns. Your pun is awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use a `std::vector` for your list  and `std::accumulate` to calcualtes sum of your list:

```
#include <vector>   // std::vector
#include <numeric>  // std::accumulate

int main()
{
    // read days
    int days;
    cout << "How many days:\n";
    cin >> days;

    // read hours for each day
    std::vector<double> hoursList;
    for(int ind=0; ind<days; ind++) {
        cout << ind+1 << ". day h: ";
        double hours;
        cin >> hours;
        hoursList.push_back(hours); // add one element at back of your vector
    }

    // clacualte sum of all hours in vector 
    double sum = std::accumulate(hoursList.begin(), hoursList.end(), 0.0); 

    cout << "Total hours: " << sum << endl;
    doubleaverage = sum/days;

    cout << "Average working day: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Hours: ";
    for( int day=0; day < (int)hoursList.size(); day ++ ) {
        cout << day+1 << ". " << hoursList[day] << std::endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to to use Vector from standard library. Try something like below. You can go through different data structures it will help in future. 
I hope this helps.

```
std::vector<double> myVectorList;
cout << "How many days:\n";
cin >> days;

for(ind=0; ind<days; ind++) {
  cout << ind+1 << ". day h: ";
  cin >> hours;
  sum += hours;
  myVectorList.push_back(hours);
}

cout << "Total hours: " << sum << endl;
average = sum/days;
cout << "Average working day: " << average << endl;
cout << "Hours: ";

for(ind=0; ind<days; ind++) {
  cout << myVectorList[ind] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Sure about the `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could primarily use an appropriate standard container class like `std::vector<double>` to gather the inputs:

```
cout << "How many days:\n";
cin >> days;

std::vector<double> dailyWorkingHours;

for(int ind=0; ind<days; ind++) {
  cout << ind+1 << ". day h: ";
  double hours;
  cin >> hours;
  dailyWorkingHours.push_back(hours);
  sum += hours;
}
```

and print out the gathered values from the container as you need to:

```
for(ind=0; ind<dailyWorkingHours.size(); ind++) {
  cout << ind + 1 << ". day h:" << dailyWorkingHours[ind] << std::endl;
}
```